# Create 3 digit numbers that are even and count them

Tags: python

I need to make a program in Python that do this:
Write a program that, for a given sequence of digits, prints the number of different three-digit even numbers that can be formed from the given digits. When forming each three-digit even number, each element of the sequence of digits can be used at most once.

The first line of the standard input contains the number of digits N, such that 3≤N≤50000. In the second row is N digits separated by one space.

Print only one number to the standard output, the requested number of three-digit numbers.

```
n=int(input())
num=[]
for i in range (n):
     num.append ()
```

**Input**

```
4

2 4 2 2
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**Explanation**
From the digits 2, 4, 2, 2, 4 different three-digit even numbers can be formed, namely 222, 224, 242, 422.

Comment: In your example why not 442, 424, 244? Also -- what is the point of such a large `N` when only the count of a digit matters and any count above 3 is superfluous? Are you counting, not just the number of even 3-digit numbers, but how often they appear? But in that case, why didn't you count 422 more than once?

Comment: Because it's needed "each element of the sequence of digits can be used at most once.".

Comment: I was looking at the `2, 4, 2, 2, 4` you had above, though I see now that this is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general solution that checks all permutations of these digits and print even numbers out of them:

```
from itertools import permutations

k = 3
c = 0
n = int(input())
num = input().strip().split(" ")

perms = set(permutations(num, k))

for perm in perms:
    t = int("".join(perm))
    if t % 2 == 0 and len(str(t)) == k:
        print(t)
        c += 1
print(c)
```

This is another solution if you don't want to use this generalized approach and just want to solve it for 3 digits:

```
c = 0
n = int(input())
num = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split(" ")]

r = set()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            if i == j or i == k or j == k:
                continue
            t = num[i] * 100 + num[j] * 10 + num[k]
            if t % 2 == 0 and len(str(t)) == 3:
                r.add(t)
print(r)
print(len(r))
```

Comment: It gives 2 digit numbers as output, too.
On 0 1 0 it gives 10 and 100.

Comment: How to count them?

Comment: If one of their test cases actually involves `N = 50000` digits then your `permutations(num,k)` will take much too long (several months at least on a typical laptop).

Comment: @JohnColeman true but It doesn't make sense to have N = 50000 when the number of digits is 3.

Comment: @Majid It doesn't make sense, but this seems to be homework (which you kindly did for them) and homework doesn't always make sense. The ability to handle N up to 50000 is part of the specification.

Comment: @JohnColeman oh you are right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Hey, guys.
Thanks for helping my daughter to solve her homework. :) I'm sorry for didn't mention that before.

The only problem is that her teacher does not allow the use of itertools, and he said that AFTER she sends him your work. When she asked BEFORE she sent can she use itertools, he told her to use whatever she wanted...

Comment: Guys, can you help me to modify this code, if that is possible?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61519262/20743521

Comment: Ok, thank you for this. It gives us a couple of leads.

Comment: @PetarTomic How are you helping your daughter by having other people do her homework for her? That isn't a good way to learn.

Comment: @John Coleman I'm not a developer, and this isn't my area of expertise, so I'm trying to help her to do homework. After she gets a grade for homework, we discuss every part of the task and try to learn from examples after we learn in theory. I know this isn't the best learning curve, but I'm trying to help as any good dad. :)

Answer (score 0):

First You should declare which user input u expect and how to handle false input.
Then the inputString is split into a list of Strings aka inputList. Now You can loop through each of those inputItem and check if they fit your expectations (is int and smaller then 10 ). Since You still deal with String Items You can try to cast ( convert them) into Int. That can fail and a unhandled failure could cripple Your script so it has to happen in an try- catch-block. If the casting works You wanna make  sure to check your matchList if You allready added a simular number before You add the new Number to Your matchList.You do so again by looping through each item. If there is mo such number yet there is a last check for if the number is uneven or 0. In that case there is one possible combination less for each number that is 0 or uneven so they are counted in the variable minusOneCombi. That will be substrated from the  maximum amount of combinations which is   the amount of numbers in you matchList multiplied with itself (pow(2)). Be very careful with the Indentations. In Python they are determining the ends of if blocks and loops.

```
InputString=(input("Enter your number stream eg 1 0 0 5 ( non numeric signs and numbers greater 9 will be ignored): "))
    inputList= inputString.split(‘ ’)
    matchList=[]
    minusOneCombi= 0
    for inputItem in inputList:
       try:
          anInt= int(inputItem)
       except ValueError:
        # Handle the exception
        print(“item is not an integer and therefore ignored”)
       
        NotYetinMatchList= True
        for MatchItem in MatchList:
           If matchItem == inputItem:
               notYetinMatchList= False
                Break
           If notYetinMatchList:
             matchList.append(anInt)
             if ((anInt % 2) != 0) OR (anInt ==0):
                minusOneCombi++
        
    NumofMatches=matchList.count()
    NumOfMatchesPow= pow(NumofMatches,2)
    Result=NumOfMatchesPow -minusOneCombi
    Print(Result)
```